# Custom Content Element with fluid for TYPO3 6.2

Tags: fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I like the way how to build custom content elements with fluid_styled_content under TYPO3 7.x

I would like to know how to do it with TYPO3 6.2.x

I'm not talking about to use DCE...

In TYPO3 7 you would do something like

```
lib.myElement < lib.fluidContent
```

I tried with fluid_content extension but I'm struggling that the lib.fluidContent does not exist in 6.2

I tried already to build lib.fluidContent by my own, based on how its done in TYPO3 7 - but without luck.

Does anybody did it successfully or found any tutorial for that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried the backport of fluid_styled_content for TYPO3 6.2? You can find it on [TER](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/content_rendering_core) and on [Github](https://github.com/patrickbroens/TYPO3.ContentRenderingCore). This should allow you to do nearly the same as in TYPO3 7. As you can see on Github, some features are missing, but Patrick is actively developing the extension. Give it a try ;)

Comment: That would be bedder a comment ;-) but yes thanks - I will probably try that next week. Keep you up to date.

Comment: Yes, after reading again, you're right. It's more of a comment. Sry. But it's still a valid answer/ way to go :)